# Using variables used in BSF post-processor as a parameter in another sampler

Tags: javascript, jmeter, load-testing

I have a BSF post-processor added to a sampler.
The script in the post-processor is:

```
var array = JSON.parse(prev.getResponseDataAsString());

array.forEach(function(object)
{
  OUT.println("patient_id: "+object.patientId);
  OUT.println("fname: "+object.fname);
  OUT.println("lname: "+object.lname);
});
```

now i want to use object.patientId, object.fname, object.lname values as parameters in another request's parameters.

E.g.

```
Thread Group
- Sampler1
    BSF Post-Processor
- Sampler2
```

I want to use the variables in the BSF Post Processor's javascript of Sampler1 as parameters in Sampler2. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily: [BSF PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_PostProcessor) provides read/write access to Jmeter Variables / Properties:

> vars - ( JMeterVariables) - gives read/write access to variables:
>   vars.get(key); vars.put(key,val); vars.putObject("OBJ1",new Object());
>   vars.getObject("OBJ2");
>
> props - (JMeterProperties - class java.util.Properties) - e.g.
>   props.get("START.HMS"); props.put("PROP1","1234");

In the simplest case you can use

```
vars.put(patientId,object.patientId.toString());
vars.put(fName,object.fname.toString());
vars.put(lName,object.lname.toString());
```

in your BSF PostProcessor to set the variables, and then get they values like

```
vars.get("patientId")
```

or

```
${patientId}
```

But since you are extracting ALL the records in foreach loop at once you cannot use this way.

In this case you have to better use something like the following: write all the records values extracted in foreach loop into csv-file, and then use e.g. [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read records one-by-one in loop and use values along with your Sampler2:

```
While Controller
    CSV Data Set Config
    Sampler 2
```

...As well, if I find another, better way, I'll be glad to know about it.

Comment: Do you mean that I should write the record values into a csv file directly from the BSF Post Processor using Javascript's File handling methods?

Can i use something like this?

function WriteToFile()
{
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var s = fso.CreateTextFile("Test.csv", true);
s.WriteLine(object.patientId.toString()+','+object.fname.toString()+','+object.lname.toString());
s.Close();
}

Comment: I tried the above code for writing the records into a csv file. I'm using JMeter on Ubuntu, which is why i think it's giving me an error for using ActiveXObject. Is there any other way around to write into a csv file using Javascript? I searched a lot around but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Also, are there any jar files that i separately need to copy into JMeter's folders if I have to use Java as a language in BSF post processor? I tried using Java for the above scene. It says:

 Problem in BSF script org.apache.bsf.BSFException: unable to load language: java

Comment: Use then [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) instead, with beanshell (read: java) code along with it. Should work for out-of-box jmeter installation, without any additional libraries required.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting Beanshell PostProcessor. :) I'm able to run Java code in it. Will use that itself to write the records into the csv file and use them with csv dataset config.