# How to print all the values with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to print all the values of a particular column name in a table in a web application. I have extracted the particular record id and the column name. I am getting printed only the first value. I am always getting the match count=1.

I need to print all the values which are matching the correlation, i.e I want some thing like 'ORD=All' similar to Load Runner. In Jmeter except that template $1$ , $2$, do i have any functions or methods to print all the captured values?

Comment: this is to complicated to understand for someone who can't see it in the screen infront. Can you give sample input/output? That way it would be easier to understand, I don't really need to know what the purpose of that is (IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

Look into these at least:

- [JMeter regex extractor forEach controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582100/jmeter-regex-extractor-foreach-controller/)
- [Pulling multiple values from JSON response using RegEx Extractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125896/pulling-multiple-values-from-json-response-using-regex-extractor/)
- [Using variables used in BSF post-processor as a parameter in another sampler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272565/using-variables-used-in-bsf-post-processor-as-a-parameter-in-another-sampler)